# reactive form date pipe in row expand

Tags: primeng, angular-reactive-forms, angular-pipe, state-management

I have a primeng grid when  select a row it popup the data on it to edit on a reactive form and there is a date column. When I expand a row in first selected two rows I can see the date pipe changes. After that it doesn't .I have used angular state management in the project

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <input class="form-control" id="dateOfBirth" type="text"
        placeholder="Date of Birth" formControlName="dateOfBirth" 
        [value]="deviceForm.get('dateOfBirth').value | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'"/>

</div>
```